# Statistics. Uniform distribution estimator variance

Tags: statistics

Let $X_1, .., X_n$ from $U([0, \theta])$. Consider estimator $X_{(1)} + X_{(n)}$ of parameter $\theta$. How to find the variance of this estimator?

P.S. I already shown that this estimator unbiased.

P.S.S. $X_{(1)} = min\{X_1, ..., X_n\}$, $X_{(n)} = max\{X_1, ..., X_n\}$.

P.S.S.S If you'll say to me, how to find $E[X_{(1)}X_{(n)}]$, I'll solve this problem

Comment: What is $X_{(i)}$?

Comment: i-th order statistics.

Comment: @enthdegree, $X_{(1)} = min\{X_1, ..., X_n\}$, $X_{(n)} = max\{X_1, .., X_n\}$